# Docker passing files back and forth between host machine and container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have a docker container that runs on the following command:

`docker run --name scraper_container -it continuumio/miniconda /bin/bash -c "...."`

The container needs to access a file that exists on the host machine. The python within the container generates a file that should be exported to the host machine.

Copying the file in with `docker cp` doesn't work since the container executes and exits immediately without giving a chance for something like a .bat file to run an additional command after the container completes its work.

I think volumes might be the solution but I've had great difficulty trying to understand how to adapt a volume to this purpose.

Ideas?

Comment: If you mount a volume, then writes to that volume from inside the container will be reflected in the host.

Comment: how does one access the volume changes from the host after the container has gone away?

Comment: If you mount e.g. `/foo:/bar`, then writing to `/bar/abc.txt` inside the container will be a persistent write to `/foo/abc.txt` outside the container.

Comment: I solved it:
`docker run -it -v /c/Users/MyName/Desktop/docker:/bar continuumio/miniconda /bin/bash`

thanks for the help!